# Are there any examples of bionicle characters fusing together in the stories?

Tags: lego, bionicle

In the Lego instructions for the first generation of Bionicle, there was a bonus section where you could fuse together three different toa and make a 'super-toa' which combined the powers of the toa used.  Was there any example of this happening in the movies or the comics, or was this just fluff for the instructions?

This section also existed in the instructions for the matoran as well, and I believe for the Bohrok.

Comment: I think it did happen in some of the earliest comics maybe but I am not totally sure... If it happened at all it's going to be in the original comics before the Bohrok-Kal I think.

Comment: Greg Farshtey has said that he was required to feature all of the "combiners" in the stories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, the Toa Kaita were featured in stories.

The [Toa Kaita](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa_Kaita), as such fusions were called, were said to have

> defeated the Manas crabs guarding Teridax's Mangaia lair, but were
>   torn back apart into Toa Mata upon entry into the heart of the lair
>   due to being so close to a being of great evil.

and

> Wairuha Nuva battled the Bohrok-Kal Kaita Ja, but was defeated.

Their major appearances take place in comics 3 and 11, as well as the Mata Nui Online game.

[image: Toa Kaita]

Comment: Cool, I read more of that article and saw that it mentioned the nuva as well.  However, were there any mention of matoran fusions, or was just an instruction bonus?

Comment: @CBredlow For the Matoran fusions, "Matoran Nui" is the name there, and they demonstrate it in one of the episodes. I believe it was framed as them showing the Toa how to fuse.